# Calendar-style view in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, view

I've done some Googling on various attempts to solve my problem but none really suffice. I'm using Access 2013, with a SQL database as the backend.

I have a database of projects. Each team member can be assigned multiple projects, and each project can have multiple team members assigned to it (yes, I have an association table).

Each project has a start and end date. What I want is to have a month view (all 31 days as thin columns), a list of team members as rows, and some way of displaying what projects they will be on and when within that month. Sometimes they overlap, so I thought about possibly splitting each member's row by the number of concurrent projects they may be on, or just having the project IDs appear on any particular day (separated by commas is they are on more than one project on one day).

I can't think of an easy way to do this. Surely 300 textboxes (say, 10 team members and 30 days) pulling 300 queries is a massive load on the server. I honestly can't think of how to do it.

Shall I attempt this in SQL (i.e. returning the project IDs in some kind of pivot view) or is there a way to manipulate this in Access itself?

Thanks

Comment: You say SQL is the back end. SQL means Structured Query Language. Do you by any chance mean SQL Server? If so, I would suggest the following. In the back end, create a table of dates and populate it with all of the dates that you will need. Create a view or stored procedure to return three columns. TeamMember, TheDate, ConcatenatedProjectNamesForThatDate. See the following link for a good article on concatenation. http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation. Then in the Access FE, use a crosstab query to generate the output that you need.

Comment: Yeah sorry that's just me typing really fast. We are using Azure SQL, which runs on SQL server. Ah yes that's a nice solution - I didn't think of creating a table with all dates (although if we're going to future proof it, it'll need to go a decade or so into the future). Thanks for the advice. P.s. the link doesn't work, but it's fine I know how to do it :)

Comment: For the future proofing, you can put a test somewhere to see if the table is populated for a year out and if, not add another year's worth of dates. Here is the link again, broken up, so hopefully it will post ok. http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries   /sql-server-grouped-concatenation